# Statistical methods for ranking units

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, ranking

**The problem:** Suppose I have an ordered sample of $n$ observations (e.g. a playlist of songs) that are ranked according to some latent (unobserved) feature, for each of which $p$ covariates are recorded. I want to build a model that is able to rank a new $m$-sample consistently with the original sample, based on their covariates.

All I can think of is to fit a logistic regression model with $2p$ variables on the probability $\pi_{ij}$ that observation $i$ is ranked higher than observation $j < i$, but I am not sure if this is a good way to go.

Are there any well-established techniques for this out there? I have attempted to search for relevant literature, but I am unsure about the specific terminology used to describe this type of problem, and I couldn't find anything about it.

I would also appreciate solutions to alternative and similar problems, as there may exist more suitable formulations to my problem.

Comment: This is more complicated than it might look.  Most people want to rank things based on linear combinations of scores for the covariates.  Provided you allow for (monotonic) nonlinear transformations of each covariate separately, that is guaranteed to work when there are two or fewer covariates.  But with $p\ge 3,$ *there is no guarantee that **any** linear combination of transformed variates will work.* Thus, as a first step, one usually tests whether it's even possible to succeed with such a model. For details, see Keeney & Raiffa, *Decisions with Multiple Objectives.*

Comment: @whuber Can you elaborate on what it means to "work" and "not work"? Thank you for your response! I'll try to look into that reference.

Comment: "Work" means the model I described is capable of reproducing the ranking.  "Not work" means no model of that form is capable of reproducing the ranking.  If there indeed is a single latent variable *and* at least one covariate is monotonically related to it, then you will be fine.  Otherwise you need to be aware of the inherent mathematical limitations in constructing linear ranking models.

Comment: @whuber Oh, I was already expecting ranking errors, that's why the first thing that came to my mind was a probabilistic model. Maybe I should rephrase my "consistently with the original sample".